# Arrange values in email template in odoo

Tags: python, odoo

i'm trying to send an email with expired vendor bills to administrator. I've stored the values in a variable line by line and assigned it to character field and attached the field in email template.

```
list=''
for invoice in invoices:
        bill_ref = invoice.number
        list += str(bill_ref)+'\n' 

invoice.details = list
```

Terminal shows the field values in line by line,

BILL/2017/0019

BILL/2017/0023

- The following Vendor Bill is about to Expire in a Week

```
            ${object.details}
```

no matter what,in the mail its just showing simply by a space. 
BILL/2017/0019 BILL/2017/0023

how can i get the details in line by line in mail?

Comment: what does your invoices contains?

Comment: @nishantkumar: its just the invoices in open state n vendorbills.       
 invoices = self.env['account.invoice'].search([('type','=','in_invoice'),('state','=','open')])